# AWS Glue Job - Active Executors Vs Needed Executors

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I am running AWS Glue job and I have allocated 50 Workers(100DPUs) of type G.2X. My job running for long time and when I look at the metrics, I have following observations:

```
1. My maximum allocated executors are 98(as per the number of DPUs provided)
2. Needed executors to run tasks are 40
3. Active executors 15 are running tasks
```

How do we increase active executors as we need 40 but only 15 are allocated/active.

Is this because of my cluster not able to provisioning enough executors to run all tasks or something else?

Any insights on this greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Bab